# How do I can avoid "'Axes' object is not subscriptable"?

Tags: matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
n_rows = 2
n_cols = 1 
fig,axes = plt.subplots(n_rows,n_cols)
for row_num in range(n_rows):
    for col_num in range(n_cols):
        ax= axes [row_num][col_num]
        ax.plot(np.random.rand(20))
        ax.set_title(f'Plot {row_num+1}),{col_num+1})')
fig.suptitle('Main title')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()this should work perfectly clearly, but it gives an error
```

`Axes' object is not subscriptable" Can you help me in finding answear?` 
I expect to know why it does not work, and how I can answer that. Also if this could be caused by different python versions?

Comment: `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(n_rows,n_cols)` is the easiest option when there are only 2 subplots. If there are more then use `fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows,n_cols)` with `axes = axes.flat` when then only requires a single loop.

Comment: *...which, then only...* - Typo